# Evaluating a function

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\arctan \dfrac{8x}{x^2-25}$$

then

$$f'(x)=\dfrac{-8 (25 + x^2)}{x^4 + 14 x^2 + 625}$$

I'm not able to find stationary points. $-8 (25 + x^2)$ seems to be always negative and $x^4 + 14 x^2 + 625$ always positive. So the whole fraction is negative for all $x \in D_f$. I concluded that such function would be decreasing, but that is not true. Please help me, what have I done wrong?

Comment: f(0)=0. So 0 is definitely a stationary point. I didn't check any of your calculations though.

Comment: shouldn't be the stationary point $f'(x_0)=0$?If so then, then $f'(0) \not= 0$ is not stationary point.

Comment: O ok- sorry- I messed up the definition of stationary point. My apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, since
$$f^\prime(x)\lt 0,$$
$f(x)$ is a decreasing function. see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28%288x%29/%28x%5E2-25%29%29).

**P.S.** Note that $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=\pm5.$

Comment: It seems like I misinterpreted graph, I mistook changes in $x=-5,x=5$ as increases. Is it appropriate to delete this question?

Comment: Well, I don't think so. I understand your way to interpret it. And it might be common mistake. I think considering the domain of $x$ at first is important.

Answer (score 0):

To find stationary points follow:
find out $f'(x)$ and then put $f'(x) = 0$
This would give:
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{-8 (25 + x^2)}{x^4 + 14 x^2 + 625}$$
$$ -8 (25 + x^2) = 0 $$
$$25 + x^2 = 0$$
implies that
$$x = \pm 5$$

Comment: You made same mistake as I did before. In real numbers there is no x that satisfy this equation $x^2=-25$ as $\sqrt{-25}$ is not defined. But thank you for taking time and answering.